# What does this reg exp means in php?

Tags: php, regex

I found a php function which is used to grab the item title from a webpage, and the reg exp it used is `/<div class=\"detail\">(.*?)<p>/si`, as in the following code: I knew that `/<div class=\"detail\">` is trying to match a specific div, and `(.*?)<p>` is matching any characters after that div and before the `<p>` with no greedy, but what does `/si` mean? thanks!

```
    <?php

    // Get the title
    function match_title( $content ) {
         preg_match( '/<div class=\"detail\">(.*?)<p>/si', $content, $result );
         isset( $result ) ? $title = trim( addslashes( $result[1] ) ) : $title = '';
         return $title;
    }

    $url = "http://a.m.taobao.com/i21708516412.htm";
    $item = file_get_contents($url);
    $title=match_title( $item );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here for all modifiers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

```
i (PCRE_CASELESS)
If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower case letters.

s (PCRE_DOTALL)
If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.
```

To sum it up: Newlines are matched and the expression is caseless.

Answer (score 0):

`/si` are the Regex Matching Modes

> `i` makes the regex match case insensitive.
>
> `s` enables "single-line mode". In this mode, the dot matches newlines.

See - [Regex Matching Modes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)